# Opinions: Viewbox

Tags: wpf, scaling, viewbox

I don't want to deal with varying screen resolutions in a WPF windows app. So, I came upon an approach which I believe deals with all of the various issues of the display - within reason.

The design of the window goes like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow.Window3"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="872" Title="My Window" SizeToContent="Manual" WindowState="Maximized" d:DesignWidth="1242"
        Height="768" Width="1024" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Closing="Window_Closing" Icon="Icon.ico" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow">

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" StretchDirection="Both">
<!-- your controls go here -->

        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With this approach, the window is scaled to align to the display, regardless of the resolution. There are corner cases, which should be mentioned;

- If the window is minimized to a very small resolution, it will be unusable, as the controls are dramatically scaled down.
- If the window is designed in a different aspect ratio than the target, then there is likely to be a large amount of whitespace displayed

Apart from the potential negative constraints called out, I am very happy with the results at this point. I don't need to worry about scrollbars, or various scaling options - it just works!

I can't be the first person to discover this, but I have not seen this approach mentioned anywhere before. I am still a newbie in the world of C#, and this is a recent discovery.

I would like to hear about negatives to the approach which I have not considered here, and hope that this will help others in their design efforts.

Thanks to all......

Comment: Read the **[editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)**, you did not format the code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the user's choice how big the elements are. He can change the DPI or the resolution (although this may not be such a good idea with LCDs, it worked well with CRTs). If he wants to be able to see lots of information in smaller font, let him do it.

If he has tiny display, you *should* display scrollbars, not illegibly small font.